# Inserting data via Rest API not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to insert data to a data extension but getting below error-

```
{
    "message": "Primary key 'SUBSCRIBER_KEY' does not exist.",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Please see below my request-

JSON -

```
[
    {
        "keys": {
            "SUBSCRIBER_KEY":"Test2"
    },


   "Values": {

      "EMAIL" : "k@test.com",
      "VERSION": "EN",
      "LANGUAGE" : "FR",
      "STORE_A" : "12458",
      "STORE_B": "23456",
      "STORE_C": "23456"
   }

}

]
```

Post - 
https://domain/hub/v1/dataevents/data extension external key/rowset

I am following deveopler doc - here -

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide what fields are on your data extension?

Comment: Are you including key: before the external key in the URL?

Comment: Hello @Rocky no I am not including any key in the URL I am using the key in the JSON body. I am following the same instructions which is given in the dev documents.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm

Comment: Hello, @Doug I have same fields in the data extension which is in the JSON body.

Comment: Hi, what I was referring to is the Data Extension's "external key" that you include in the URL. It should be preceded by "key:" I ran into this error last week. I don't remember for sure how I fixed it, but I think I had omitted "key:" in the URL. In any case, it's required if you're using the DE external key rather than ID, as your question implies. From the documentation: "Data extension external key, included in URL as key:your external key value here. Required if an ID is not provided." (Sorry, didn't mean to tag Doug in my initial version of this comment.)

Comment: Hello, @Rocky Thank you very much it is working now.
I was missing the Key; work in front of the data extension external key.
I put the work key before the External key, and now it is working.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it's working.